# BAT script to run different commands on different machines

Tags: windows, scripting

I need to write a .bat script that executes different sets of commands based on which machine it is running on.

If it's running on a machine called "analysis" it needs to run:

```
mv *.pdf D:\Export\Worksheet
mv *.csv D:\Export\Statistics
```

Otherwise it needs to run:

```
mv *.pdf C:\Export\Worksheet
mv *.csv C:\Export\Statistics
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COMPUTERNAME` environment variable has what you're looking for.

Something like the following should help you:

```
if /i "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "analysis" (
    mv *.pdf D:\Export\Worksheet
    mv *.csv D:\Export\Statistics
) else (
    mv *.pdf C:\Export\Worksheet
    mv *.csv C:\Export\Statistics
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the environment variable COMPUTERNAME.
Start with

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME%
```

Basically, I think you want:

```
if %COMPUTERNAME% == analysis ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use %COMPUTERNAME% as others have pointed out.  You may want to make your script more readable by defining a local variable containing the path that varies between the machines and then using that subsequently to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use something like:

```
::Common settings
SET X=....
....

GOTO %COMPUTERNAME%

:COMPUTER1
::Commands for #1
....
GOTO :EOF

:COMPUTER2
::Commands for #2
....
GOTO :EOF
```